# Scrolling in nested Listbox wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, scroll

Some Background: 
We are trying to build a scheduling control like outlook with some custom functionality.
I have already gone through the similar post in Code Project but we tend to take slightly different approach (trying to use MVVM approach).

Problem:
Currently we have a Listbox with 3 items. Each item in the list box is another Listbox with borders as items. For E.g. the XAML code looks like this

```
<ListBox Name="MasterListBox" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="500" Width="500">
              <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBoxItem >
            <ListBox Name="Child1" Height="240">
                <ListBoxItem>
                    <Border Width="200" Background="Red" Height="40"></Border>
                </ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem >
                    <Border Width="200" Background="Blue" Height="40"></Border>
                </ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem >
                    <Border Width="200"  Background="Green" Height="40"></Border>
                </ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox>
        </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem >
            <ListBox Name="Child2" Height="240">
                <ListBoxItem >
                    <Border Width="200" Background="Yellow" Height="40"></Border>
                </ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem >
                    <Border Width="200" Background="Green" Height="40"></Border>
                </ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem >
                    <Border Width="200"  Background="Pink" Height="40"></Border>
                </ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox>
        </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem >
            <ListBox Name="Child3" Height="240">
                <ListBoxItem >
                    <Border Width="200" Background="Aqua" Height="40"></Border>
                </ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem >
                    <Border Width="200" Background="Beige" Height="40"></Border>
                </ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem >
                    <Border Width="200"  Background="Brown" Height="40"></Border>
                </ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox>
        </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

The problem is when I click on the 1st item(Child1) of the MasterListBox in the white area and drag right, the MasterListBox list box scroll to right, But when I click on the subitem (for e.g. say red border) and drag right the MasterListBox doesn’t scroll right. 
I am aware that I am trying to drag the item of the inner list box and that’s the reason the outer list box is not scrolling, But it there a way we can override this. I want to select the inner item also so cannot set IsHitTestVisible="False" for inner item.

Thanks you for looking into this. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Regards
Saurabh

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to create drag-to-scroll functionality using the inner `ListBox`'s `OnPreviewLeftMouseDown`,`OnPreviewMouseMove`, and `OnPreviewMouseUp` events to implement the desired effect.

Another way is to find the event(s) responsible for the drag-to-scroll functionality within the inner `ListBox` and to override the event handler so that the event gets routed to the outer `ListBox`.

Comment: Thanks Jakub for taking a look. But please can you elaborate on your approach. I am not very efficient on WPF so if you could let me know some detail as to what do you mean by override the event handler. If possible can you direct me to any link or example you are aware. Again thanks  a lot for replying